# Linked Sub-report Organizing Strategy

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

Is there a logic to deciding how to structure a master report with sub-reports?

For example, I have a 360 (employee feedback) report I'm trying to make, where there are 4 different ways of presenting the data. Each different presentation has a different page header & uses different groupings. So I think I need to make each presentation into a separate report & then bind them all together in a master report with subs.

But, how should I structure the master.

For example, should the master be the one with the most complex data, and then the other, simpler, sub-reports get tucked into headers & footers relative to where they need to be in relation to that 'core' report? Or should I make the title page be the 'master', with conditionally suppressed page headers and then put each way of presenting the data as a sub-report into a separate group header in order within that report?

i.e. what is a good organizational strategy for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your subreports to repeat for each group of data or each detail record in your main report, then your subreports belong in a group or details area.

Another thing to consider is whether your subreports would ever make sense as 'standalone' reports - could they exist outside the context of the main report? In that case, design them this way, and make use of the 'reimport subreport' feature on your eventual main report(s) to automatically pick up changes.

Otherwise it doesn't really matter, as long as you can get the layout you want - in that case, just do what is simplest.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I appreciate the response.